# alarm manager does not launch android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Well in my app I am trying the following functionality. I want depending on the date and the time, the user to receiver some notifications.

For example:

1. September 9, 19.13 receive notification with message1
2. September 10, 07.30, with message 2,
3. same day, but 11.50, with message 3 and so on...

I used an alarm and a push bar notification but it worked only for the first one. So I serached for that and is is stated that I must use a repeating alarm manager.

Before I post my code I want to clarify some things:
1) I am thinking it that it should work like that:
i must check every 1-2 min, what time is it, fetch my next "time" from an array that events are stored, and set ana alarm for that, right? Then given that this bynch of code will run every 1-2 minutes, i will check again, fetch the next event,set alarm for that time and so on.

Am I correct?

So to begin with, i am trying to implement a repeating alarm manager which every 1 min will display me a Toast message (If I do this and replacing the toast message with get_next_event()  and set_next_notification() will do the job I think. - These function are working fine in my project with only one alarm being set).

But problem is that when I am starting my service I see nothing.

here is my code:

**Alarm.java**

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             Toast.makeText(context, "Starting Alarm Manager", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Setting Alarm Manager", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 , pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
```

YourService.java

```
public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();    
        Toast.makeText(YourService.this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

    }

    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        Toast.makeText(YourService.this, "Setting from Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

DemoActivity.java

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
        Toast.makeText(ServicesDemo.this, "Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
      startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
      break;
    case R.id.buttonStop:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
      stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
      break;
    }
  }
```

So i press the button, I see that "button is pressed" , i see that "service created" but then none of the toasts that alarm started are being shown. And of course, I see nothing every 1 min.

here is my manifest.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".ServicesDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".YourService" />
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>

  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

So what do I need to change in my code or in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `AlarmManager` for this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html .

Comment: do you have any links -tutorials? I have seen this ut every sample I saw on the web does not seem to working.

Comment: that's exaclty the code I used in my post. But it is not working.